# Do Gödel numbers have a practical use?

Tags: logic, soft-question, prime-numbers, information-theory

Is there any example of Gödel numbers being actually used in practice? If so for what purpose?

Comment: NO. ___________

Comment: Um, isn't proving Godel's theorem practical?

Comment: By "in practice" I mean outside of mathematics.

Comment: Why would a usage in a proof not qualify as 'practical'? Goedel numbers are used very frequently in set theory. A reason for this is that they have a uniform $\Sigma_{1}$-definition over transitive models that are closed under the pairing functions. Sure, there are other such codings, but the Goedel numbering is a natural candidate and incredible useful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. The Information Age is based on the Gödel number.

A program in the programming language Python, for instance, is stored internally in the computer as a base-128 integer, via the ASCII which encodes characters as integers. If you wish to execute the program, you provide it to the computer as a Gödel number, expressed in base 128 (by typing in certain keys on your keyboard), and you tell the computer to execute the program with that Gödel number. You're not coding Turing machines directly, but you're coding a Turing-equivalent form of machine.

Comment: This refers to recognizing that programs made of finite strings can be mapped to natural numbers (so $\mathbb{N}$ is a programing language) and that there exists a computable function, that when given the number of the program and its input it can compute its output. This is the utm theorem (universal Turing machine) and tells us that it is possible to write interpreters.

Comment: Even Python does not run on the "input number", but goes in one way or another through the standard chain of tokenization and syntax tree derivation to compile to byte code and run that. The key point of Gödel numbers IMHO is to be able to use the mathematics on natural numbers and set theory, esp. Cantor diagonalization, to make statements, esp. incompleteness results, for wide classes of numbers (and thus programs). This I do not see applied here.

Comment: @mvw The question of how the input number is executed is merely a matter of the implementation of the Gödel numbering scheme, surely.

Comment: We don't treat programs as single numbers any more than we treat English sentences as single words.

Comment: The important thing is that there is a mapping from mathematical statements expressed in a formal language to the objects that the formal language is "about", so that statements such as "X is provable" correspond to statements of the language.  It happened that the
primitive objects in language such as Peano Arithmetic are natural numbers, so that's what Gödel wants to use in his encoding.  I suppose it might have been more convenient to use a theory of finite arrays of natural numbers.

Comment: The way that Unicode encodings such as utf8 and utf16 represent characters as numbers is certainly very closely related to Goedel numberings.

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea of Gödel numbers is to establish a mapping between logical statements and natural numbers. This allows to apply reasoning on natural numbers, and those results can be translated back into reasoning on logical statements.

Related mappings are:

- the mapping between Turing machines, one embodiment of computable functions, and natural numbers. A main result is the Halting problem.
  It influenced the recognition by engineers that compilers and software controlled systems can not be trusted fully, which plays a role in environments like atomic power plants.
- the mapping between logical statements and finite automata, which allows for model checking

So my impression is that the idea has had no direct practical application, like general relativity and GPS, but still was very influential to computer science.

Answer (score 2):

The key idea of Gödel numbering is that logical syntax can be treated as data. Applications of this concept pervade modern computing.